# error C2804: binary 'operator +' has too many parameters (compiling with VC 120)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

Writing my own vector class (for a game engine) and overloading '+' operator in Visual Studio 2013 CPlusPlus project (using VC runtime 120), it is throwing me compiler error:

> Error: too many parameters for this operator function.

Code snippet from `Vector.hpp` file below.

**Vector.hpp**

```
class Vector
{
private:
    double i;
    double j;
    double k;
public:
    Vector(double _i, double _j, double _k)
    {
        i = _i;
        j = _j;
        k = _k;
    }

    Vector& operator+=(const Vector& p1)
    {
        i += p1.i;
        j += p1.j;
        k += p1.k;
        return *this;
    }

    //Some other functionality...

    Vector operator+(const Vector& p1, Vector& p2) //Error is thrown here...
    {
        Vector temp(p1);
        return temp += p2;
    }
};
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Don't want to make my operator overload non-member function.

Comment: `Vector operator+(const Vector& p1, Vector& p2)` should be declare out of class

Comment: as a member function it has `this` implicitly as first parameter, but you want to supply two more

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When `operator+` is defined inside class, left operand of operator is current instance. So, to declare a overload of `operator+` you have 2 choices

- inside class, with only one parameter which is right operand
- outside of class, with two parameters, left and right operands.

**Choice 1: outside class**

```
class Vector
{
private:
    double i;
    double j;
    double k;
public:
    Vector(double _i, double _j, double _k)
    {
        i = _i;
        j = _j;
        k = _k;
    }

    Vector& operator+=(const Vector& p1)
    {
        i += p1.i;
        j += p1.j;
        k += p1.k;
        return *this;
    }

    //Some other functionality...


};

Vector operator+(const Vector& p1, const Vector& p2)
{
    Vector temp(p1);
    temp += p2;
    return temp;
}
```

**Choice 2: inside class**

```
class Vector
{
private:
    double i;
    double j;
    double k;
public:
    Vector(double _i, double _j, double _k)
    {
        i = _i;
        j = _j;
        k = _k;
    }

    Vector& operator+=(const Vector& p1)
    {
        i += p1.i;
        j += p1.j;
        k += p1.k;
        return *this;
    }



    Vector operator+(const Vector & p2)
    {
        Vector temp(*this);
        temp += p2;
        return temp;
    }

};
```

You can see how should be declared operators here : [C/C++ operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Answer (score 1):

one more possibility is by using the friend keyword.

```
friend Vector operator+(const Number& n1, const Number& n2)
    {
        Vector temp(n1);
        temp+=n2;
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer question. It is not a question about friendness here. Also, your declaration of friendness isn't correct => declare as friend inside class, using `friend` keyword  followed by only declaration and write implementation of function outside of class, without `friend` keyword. And finally, IMHO, use `friend` only when it is needed, and here, it doesn't